# wso2: ws-discovery integration

Tags: wso2, soa, esb, ws-discovery

WSO2 WS-Discovery Integration

We're trying to integrate WS-Discovery with the Carbon products WSO2 Governance Registry and WSO2 ESB having
Apache CXF Web Service stack configured via Spring running on a Tomcat sending hello messages to the 
Discovery Proxy (localhost:9443/services/DiscoveryProxy) on WSO2 Greg.

Therefore we added cxf-services-ws-discovery-service.jar and cxf-services-ws-discovery-api.jar to the
classpath in Tomcat. Further we set the spring bus property org.apache.cxf.service.ws-discovery.address
to the URL address of the WS-Discovery Proxy on WSO2 Greg to run WS-Discovery in managed mode. By running 
Tomcat and WSO2 Greg following error messages is logged in wso2Carbon.log (WSO2 Greg) ...

```
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-07-15 11:45:03,411]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.discovery.proxy.DiscoveryProxy} -  Service Discovery Failed. Retrying after 10s. {org.wso2.carbon.discovery.proxy.DiscoveryProxy}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-07-15 11:45:03,458] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager} -  Failed to add artifact: artifact id: urn:uuid:003aa9d9-2c9f-4e0b-8415-c99632226ee3, path: /trunk/services/org/oasis_open/docs/ws_dd/ns/discovery/_2009/_01/DiscoveredService_1373881503442. An exception occurred while executing handler chain. String index out of range: -1 {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. String index out of range: -1
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2525)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1005)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:697)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:465)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:658)
                at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager.addGovernanceArtifact(GovernanceArtifactManager.java:155)
                at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.services.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:116)
                at org.wso2.carbon.discovery.util.DiscoveryServiceUtils.addService(DiscoveryServiceUtils.java:152)
                at org.wso2.carbon.discovery.proxy.DiscoveryProxy$1.run(DiscoveryProxy.java:89)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
                at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.utils.EndpointUtils.deriveEndpointFromUrl(EndpointUtils.java:674)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.utils.EndpointUtils.saveEndpoint(EndpointUtils.java:483)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.utils.EndpointUtils.saveEndpointsFromServices(EndpointUtils.java:280)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.ServiceMediaTypeHandler.put(ServiceMediaTypeHandler.java:353)
                at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
                ... 14 more
```

We tried to solve this issue for several hours by reading WSO2 product documentation and searching through
several forums, blogs etc. . Unfortunely we couldn't find a solution.

Remark: WS-Discovery integration with WSO2 Application Server instead of Tomcat just worked fine.
But when using WSO2 ESB as an discovery client to discover services from WSO2 Greg the wizard to create proxy services out of the
discoverd services on WSO2 ESB is missing the publishWSDL xml tag after creating the proxy. This tag must be added 
manually. Is there a way to get this done without editing this additionally??

We would be grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you intercept the Discovery hello requests sent to GReg via Tomcat and the Application Server and compare the two? That should give an idea on what's missing. Also post those here if possible so we can have a look

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick reply

We intercepted the hello requests sent to WSO2 GReg via Tomcat and the WSO2 Application server. For this purpose we used soapUI mock
services. The message requests of the soap envelopes look as follows ...

Tomcat:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01">
<soap:Header>
  <wsa:Action>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Hello</wsa:Action>
  <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e01ce7dc-53c0-4b36-b7d5-0e84e3bd6a5d</wsa:MessageID>
  <wsa:To>https://localhost:9443/services/DiscoveryProxy</wsa:To>
  <wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/none</wsa:Address>
  </wsa:ReplyTo>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ns2:Hello xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01">
     <EndpointReference>
        <Address>urn:uuid:be46c1fc-1646-4bcc-8715-1aed4040fdd5</Address>
        <ReferenceParameters/>
     </EndpointReference>
     <ns2:Types xmlns:ns3="http://user.service.scheck.server.tia/">ns3:IZ3UserService</ns2:Types>
     <ns2:Scopes/>
     <ns2:XAddrs>/userService</ns2:XAddrs>
     <ns2:MetadataVersion>1</ns2:MetadataVersion>
  </ns2:Hello>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

WSO2 Application Server:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">              
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <mns:serviceName xmlns:mns="http://www.wso2.org/ws/discovery">echo</mns:serviceName>
  <mns:wsdlURI xmlns:mns="http://www.wso2.org/ws/discovery">http://10.200.2.114:9764/services/echo?wsdl</mns:wsdlURI>
  <wsa:To>https://localhost:9443/services/DiscoveryProxy</wsa:To>
  <wsa:ReplyTo>
     <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/none</wsa:Address>
  </wsa:ReplyTo>
  <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:d21e108b-34a2-4313-8b12-a22015567a51</wsa:MessageID>
  <wsa:Action>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Hello</wsa:Action>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <wsd:Hello xmlns:wsd="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01">
     <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Address>urn:uuid:439a1cd5-fb36-40e2-a54e-e0cb7f3409e4</wsa:Address>
     </wsa:EndpointReference>
     <wsd:Types xmlns:axis2ns1="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">axis2ns1:echoPortType</wsd:Types>
     <wsd:Scopes>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/DefaultScope</wsd:Scopes>
     <wsd:XAddrs>https://10.200.2.114:9444/services/echo http://10.200.2.114:9764/services/echo</wsd:XAddrs>
     <wsd:MetadataVersion>1</wsd:MetadataVersion>
  </wsd:Hello>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comparing both message requests we noticed that there are some tags missing like serviceName, wsdlURI and most important
in our opinion the XAddrs. By adding the XAddrs manually to an soapUI request we were able to register the cxf service
on WSO2 GReg. Maybe you can give us an advice how this could be achieved by configuring cxf via spring or by annotating our
web service implementations.

Thanks again..this helped us very much!!